# Move a square using the coordinate system in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, coordinates

I need to move this square using _dragTask() function, and i also need to do to it by using the coordinate system. Anyone can do that?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      MainContainer: {backgroundColor: "#282c34", display: "flex", minHeight: "100vh"},
      ObjectMap: [],
    }
    this._createObject = this._createObject.bind(this);
    this._createBox = this._createBox.bind(this);
    this._buttonCreateBox1 = this._buttonCreateBox1.bind(this);
    this._dragTask = this._dragTask.bind(this);
  }

  _createObject = (object) => {
    var ObjectMap = this.state.ObjectMap;
    ObjectMap.push(object);
    this.setState({ObjectMap: ObjectMap});
  }

  _createBox = (style) => {
    var object = {position: "absolute", top: this.state.positionX, left: this.state.positionY};
    var styleObject = Object.assign({},
      object, style
    )
    return (
      <div style={styleObject} draggable="true" onDragEnd={(event) => {this._dragTask(event)}}>

      </div>
      );

  }

  _dragTask(event) {
    event.persist();
    this.setState({positionX: event.screenX, positionY: event.screenY}, () => { console.log("Page X:"+ this.state.positionX + " Page Y:" + this.state.positionY); });
  }

  _buttonCreateBox1 = () => {
    this._createObject(this._createBox({backgroundColor: "white", width: "300px", height: "300px"}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.state.MainContainer}>
        <button type="button" onClick={ this._buttonCreateBox1 }>Click Me!</button>
        {
          this.state.ObjectMap.map((item, index) => {
            return item
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Right now, the object it created by printed in the screen by the mainloop, and added to it by _createObject() function.

Answer (score 2):

just change your `_dragTask` method to this

```
  _dragTask(event) {
    event.target.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    event.target.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
  }
```

and change the style of the wrapper to have `position: relative`

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      MainContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "#282c34",
        position: "relative",
        display: "flex",
        minHeight: "100vh"
      },
      ObjectMap: []
    };
    ...
```

checkout this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-example-zx71g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to see full example